# Marginal distribution of two jointly distributed Random Variables that are dependent

Tags: probability

[image]

Find the Marginal Distribution of $X$ (note: $c=1/8$).

Clearly, $X$ is dependent on $Y$, since the value Y takes restricts the domain of $X$. Would this affect how the marginal distribution is computed? Or would you just do the usual?

[image]

What happens to the domain of $X$? Is it simply $- \infty < x < \infty $ ?

I feel like I am missing something conceptually here. Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the joint density function is $0$ unless $y\ge |x|$. So for $f_X(x)$ we integrate $c(y^2-x^2)e^{-y}$ from $y=|x|$ to $\infty$.   The domain of $f_X(x)$ will indeed be all of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Remark:** The function obtained in the OP is not a density function over any interval. For unless it is restricted to a subset of $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$, it is sometimes negative. And if restricted, it integrates to less than $1$.

Comment: So [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2F8%29*e%5E%28-y%29*%28y%5E2-x%5E2%29+dy+from+abs%28x%29+to+infinity) would be the correct answer? And $- \infty < x < \infty$ ?

Comment: The answer above said the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$, so yes, $-\infty\lt x\lt \infty$. The Wolfram Alpha answer, maybe because Alpha is complex oriented, is a little weird. Note that $|x|^2-x^2=0$, so a couple of terms in the Alpha answer cancel.

Comment: Thanks! I am satisfied now.

Comment: You are welcome. Some people advocate the use of indicator functions to guard against integrating over the wrong domain. If you are comfortable with that, use it. I usually just make a sketch.